# OCaml constructor error

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to create a function for object creation, and I am receiving a very generic `Error: Syntax error` on the function. The class:

```
    class dataframe csv_file = 
        object
        val mutable csv = csv_file
        end
```

The function to create the object:

```
    let import_data dataframe_name filepath = 
       let dataframe_name = new dataframe (Csv.load filepath);;
```

note: `(Csv.load file)` returns the user defined type `t : string list list` however I don't see this as being a problem since `csv_file` is polymorphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure

```
let foo =
  let bar = baz;;
```

is syntactically incorrect. You should use either

```
let foo =
  baz;;
```

of

```
let foo =
  let bar = baz in
  foobar;;
```